# Text wrapping under label on new line

Tags: html, css

I have a page, a confirmation page.

On the left side `<label>`, in the middle `padding`, and on the right `<span>`

The text in the span, when too long, wraps underneath the label, instead of under the width of the label, like an `inline-block`.

```
<label>Label1:</label>
<span class="class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</span>
<label>Label2:</label>
<span class="class"> sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, </span>
```

**CSS**

```
label, span {
     width: 45%
}
label {
     float: left;
}
```

How can I make it such that the CSS is 45% and on multiple lines?

Comment: Side note, typo in your example. The second CSS rule ends in `{` when it should be `}`. Also, is this what you're after http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9h45365b/1/?

Comment: @j08691 Yes, but the `spans` belong to the `labels`, and the `labels` aren't being pushed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the spans and the labels to `inline-block`, they will behave exactly as you want.

```
label, span {
    width: 45%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

See [this update to j08691's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/9h45365b/5/).

But your question seems to indicate that you don't want that, is that right?

Comment: for some reason I had `display: inline-block` commented out. I didn't make a note of why, unfortunately. Your answer works, and to my knowledge is the most appropriate answer, so I'll go with it.